# @keyframes animation not working on iOS only

Tags: css, ios, mobile, css-animations, keyframe

I have developed a webpage using HTML/CSS and am using @keyframes to animate an infinite vertical movement of a list of 4 texts(showing one text at a time). The code works on all the browsers in all android devices, macs and iPad. But it doesn't work only on all the browsers of an iPhone. I have tried the below solutions and they haven't worked:
1.I tried using only @keyframes.
2.I tried using both @keyframes and @-webkit-keyframes.
3. I tried using both @keyframes and @-webkit-keyframes with different animation names for both the keyframes.
4. I tried using translate3d instead of translateY.

Below is the code of my keyframes:

```
   .mobile.up p {
     a{
       padding-left: 0px !important;
       padding-right: 0px !important;
       padding-top: 0px !important;
     color: #F2F4F6;
     font-family: 'Gotham Medium';
     border-bottom: 1px solid #F2F4F6;
      padding-bottom: 2px;
       font-style: normal;
       font-size: 12px;
       line-height: 200%;
     }
    transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    // -moz-transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
      -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    }
   .mobile.up p:nth-child(1) {
    animation: up-mobile-one 20s ease infinite;
    // -moz-animation: up-mobile-one-moz 20s ease infinite;
      -webkit-animation: up-mobile-one-webkit 20s ease infinite;
   }
   .mobile.up p:nth-child(2) {
    animation: up-mobile-two 20s ease infinite;
    // -moz-animation: up-mobile-two-moz 20s ease infinite;
      -webkit-animation: up-mobile-two-webkit 20s ease infinite;
  }

   .mobile.up p:nth-child(3) {
    animation: up-mobile-three 20s ease infinite;
    // -moz-animation: up-mobile-three-moz 20s ease infinite;
      -webkit-animation: up-mobile-three-webkit 20s ease infinite;
   }

   .mobile.up p:nth-child(4) {
    animation: up-mobile-four 20s ease infinite;
    // -moz-animation: up-mobile-four-moz 20s ease infinite;
      -webkit-animation: up-mobile-four-webkit 20s ease infinite;
    }


   /**Keyframes **/
   @keyframes up-mobile-one {
       0%{
            transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
        opacity: 1;
        }
        5% {
            transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
        }
        25% {
            transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        opacity: 0;
        }
        100%{
            transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        opacity: 0;
        }
   }
   @keyframes up-mobile-two {
       0% {
            transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
        opacity: 1;
        }
        25% {
         transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
         opacity: 1;
       }
       30%{
           transform:translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
           opacity: 1;
       }
       50% {
         transform:translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
         opacity: 0;
       }
       100%{
            transform:translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
        opacity: 0;
        }
   }
   @keyframes up-mobile-three {
       0% {
            transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
        opacity: 1;
        }
        50% {
         transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
         opacity: 1;
       }
       55% {
         transform:translate3d(0, -200%, 0);
         opacity: 1;
       }
       75%{
            transform:translate3d(0, -200%, 0);
        opacity: 0;
        }
       100%{
            transform:translate3d(0, -200%, 0);
        opacity: 0;
        }
   }

   @keyframes up-mobile-four {
       0% {
        transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
      opacity: 1;
        }
        75% {
         transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
         opacity: 1;
       }
       80% {
         transform:translate3d(0, -300%, 0);
         opacity: 1;
       }
       100%{
            transform:translate3d(0, -300%, 0);
        opacity: 0;
        }
   }


   /** Webkit Keyframes **/
   @-webkit-keyframes up-mobile-one-webkit {
       0%{
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
        opacity: 1;
       }
       5% {
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
       }
       25% {
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        opacity: 0;
       }
       100%{
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        opacity: 0;
       }
   }
   @-webkit-keyframes up-mobile-two-webkit {
       0% {
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
        opacity: 1;
       }
       25% {
         -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
         opacity: 1;
       }
       30%{
           -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
           opacity: 1;
       }
       50% {
         -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
         opacity: 0;
       }
       100%{
         -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
        opacity: 0;
       }
   }
   @-webkit-keyframes up-mobile-three-webkit {
       0% {
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
        opacity: 1;
       }
       50% {
         -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
         opacity: 1;
       }
       55% {
         -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, -200%, 0);
         opacity: 1;
       }
       75%{
         -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, -200%, 0);
        opacity: 0;
       }
       100%{
         -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, -200%, 0);
        opacity: 0;
       }
   }

   @-webkit-keyframes up-mobile-four-webkit {
       0% {
       -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
      opacity: 1;
       }
       75% {
         -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
         opacity: 1;
       }
       80% {
         -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, -300%, 0);
         opacity: 1;
       }
       100%{
         -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, -300%, 0);
        opacity: 0;
       }
   }
```

Comment: the only reason I can think of is, the page has not re-downloaded the updated files

Comment: Also try this: before every transform within keyframes, put -webkit-transform: instead of just transform.

Comment: When I check on simulator, I can see the new values applied to the elements. So updated files are present, I believe.

Comment: Do you mean I should put -webkit-transform in the @keyframe rule too? I have -webkit-transform in the @-webkit-keyframe rule which is being applied to the element in the mobile version.

Comment: yes its worth a try

Comment: This solution is not working unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a half second delay to my animation got it to work properly on iPhone browsers.